# Why is my search bar not aligning to the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a search bar with bootstrap and the problem is that I want it to align to the right side of the nav bar, instead it is staying on the left. Here is the issue:

[image]

FYI, the search text is being overlapped by the logo, but we don't need to worry about that. The problem is I want the search bar to be on the right side of the screen. By the way, the navbar element is parented to a container-fluid, **but not a row**.

**Why is it not aligned to the right side of the navbar?**

```css
#search-bar {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  height: 28px;
  width: 32%;
  margin-right: 40px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar col-12"> <img class="navbar-brand" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Ventr Logo" width="100">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="search-bar" align="right">
</nav>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Your input _does_ align to the right. See the demo I created from your code. Please update the snippet using the link to show the problem.

Comment: Other tips: Don't use inline styles (or the `width` attribute)--it's a pain for everyone. Use CSS and Bootstrap classes (`w-100`). Bootstrap provides all the layout you could need (`float-end`). Have a look at all the docs to become familiar. Avoid setting heights on Bootstrap form elements unless you do it across the board and adjust padding, etc. Things get wonky. Use [input sizing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/input-group/#sizing) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, Bootstrap is not necessary for this, I'm just going to use regular `HTML` and `CSS`.

Answer (score -1):

Go take a look at the bootstrap navigations that are pre-built. In most cases, they've been the base of what I needed. You can customise them as much as you really want. The code is provided and the search bars are aligned to the right from the start.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).